# How to know that an iOS device is in a certain vicinity?

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ibeacon, eddystone

I have a requirement of building an app such that it detects that the device is in the car (assumed) or not.

I did some research over it and found that iBeacons may be handy for this purpose but I am looking for any alternative before falling to iBeacons all together.

I also considered the NFC stickers but to get the data from it, the NFC stickers should be scanned consistently and how could I detect that device is not near by the sticker.

Does EddyStone from Google provide good services for iOS and Android both?

Comment: Add to that the fact that iOS doesn't have the capability to read NFC stickers, iBeacon is your best solution

Comment: iOS developer don't have access (yet?) to the NFC Chip present in certains iPhone (not all, whereas BLE for iBeacon is for iPhone 4S and newer).

Comment: Does iBeacons constantly feed the device so that I can detect when it is disconnected?

Comment: Yes, you will get region entry/exit notifications. Region exit can take a few minutes to arrive

Answer (score 1):

**A beacon will work well for this use case.**  The mobile device will detect the beacon packets sent every second or more, providing rapid callbacks to tell you if the device is near the beacon in the car.

Both Eddystone and iBeacon can work on iOS and Android, but iBeacon offers real advantages in terms of detection speed on iOS, as Apple has optimized detections of iBeacons to happen within a couple of seconds of detection in most cases.  Eddystone will take significantly longer on iOS.  On Android, detection speed is the same for both formats.

When the mobile device goes out of range of the beacon in the car, your app will get a callback indicating this has happened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do some more digging and update here if I find something interesting.